# Populate a Filter web part from a List item and execute

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, filter, connected-web-parts

I have a Business Data Related List called *Projects*. It is connected to a Business Data Item, so it has the option to select an item (the two-way arrow next to an Item). From this List I need to pass on click the selected value (*Project Name*) to a *Filter web part* which will automatically send filter values to a Document Library, called *Project Documents*. The Filter can not be connected to the List as there is no List name in it's *Connections > Get Default Value From* option. The List, Filter and Library are all on the same page.

I suppose the best way to do this is with a JavaScript / JQuery, maybe SPServices even, but I do not know how. Any thoughts are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connected web parts should still work.  Have you tried selecting an alternate column first?  The reason you don't see the option is because there is a data type mismatch.  If you select something of the same or a compatible data type, it should let you connect the web parts. I think Project Name could be the "field with edit menu" type, you might try the one with no "special" behavior -- just plain text field.
Now because this is a Business Data web part it might be harder to get the right field, but you may be able to change the BCS metadata to produce a "plain" column for you to filter with.
You could use the javascript approach, but connecting web parts is the easiest when all of them are on the same page.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks, I did some research on connected web parts after reading your answer, but still have not found a way to connect the list to the filter, with respect to the column type. It would be great if I could connect the List to the Document Library directly following your advice. Will continue to test, and your answer is useful.